# Is this string join implementation really O(n^2)?

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory

I was reading a popular book on algorithm questions and saw an implementation of string join such as the following:

```
public String joinTheStrings(String[] theStrings){
     String joinedString = "";
     for(String singleString : theStrings){
          joinedString = joinedString + singleString;
     }
     return joinedString;
}
```

The author then went on to claim this implementation is `O(n^2)`, and that an optimization would be to use a `StringBuffer` in place of `joinedString`, which they claimed would make the algorithm `O(n)`. However, I fail to see how the original algorithm is `O(n^2)` - It appears to me that for N words there will be N operations (adding the strings together).

> Update: Thank you for responses. It looks like I am confused about how the author treats the copying of an array of characters (which I would think to be a constant) as another factor of N in the amortized runtime?

Comment: I am guessing "+" involves copying both strings into a new one and returning that.

Comment: Are you assuming that `+` is an O(1) operation on strings...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes, and maybe that is where I am wrong?

Comment: A string is really not a single "atomic" kind of thing, it's more like an array of characters.

Comment: @harold how come in the amortized analysis, the author seems to treat the array of characters (which I would think a constant) as another factor of N?

Comment: @stevebot he's probably taking `n` to be the total size of the input, not the number of strings, and that makes sense because you're copying the interior of the strings, not so much the references. So, to turn that around, why is the array of strings an other factor of `n`? That's because you keep copying an increasingly long part again and again. For example, in the second concatenation, the result of the first concatenation has to be copied again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` operator used to create a new `String` by copying both of its operands's characters in a new `char[]` with size `firstString.length() + secondString.length()`, but for that it had to iterate over the chars of both of them. That's where your hidden inner loop lies.

However, recent versions of JDK optimize string concatenation at compile time by automatically turning it into a `StringBuilder`'s `append()` operation. The book you mention must be quite old, nowadays `StringBuffer` is not used in general, because it's synchronized.

Anyway, the compiler might not be smart enough to extract `StringBuilder` instantiation *outside* of the loop, creating new string builders for each iteration, thereby reducing its usefulness as a performance optimization. So it's not a bad idea to write this by hand:

```
public String joinTheStrings(String[] theStrings) {
     StringBuilder joinedString = new StringBuilder();
     for (String singleString : theStrings)
          joinedString.append(singleString);
     return joinedString.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar. Isn't the input N words and not N characters, so how does iterating over the characters affect the amortized runtime? If there are N words, and we iterate over k characters, isn't this O(nk)~O(n)?

Comment: @stevebot Words vs characters is a distraction; let's assume 1-character words. The problem is that, for N/2 iterations of the loop, the left operand `joinedString` in `joinedString + singleString` consists of at least N/2 words/characters.

Comment: Granted, the input is an array of strings, but each string is made of characters. To concatenate them, you have to iterate over each of the chars. Beware, your book seems outdated - please read my complete answer

Comment: @Oscar Thank you, best answer I could have hoped for.